# Javascript http regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am currently using the following to convert `[url=][/url]` to a html link:

```
s = message.replace(/\[url=([^\]]+)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
```

That work's fine.

I then added on another replace function using a regex to replace `www` with `http://www` like so:

```
s = message.replace(/\[url=([^\]]+)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
.replace(/www/g, "http://www");
```

This is probably not the best/efficient method and also does not support `https://` which is not a priority at the moment but is something I would like to include at some point. Could someone please advise me on what I could do to improve the regex?

Comment: This isn't really good for the Question/Answer format. - It's too broad.  "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format"

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - I do see where you're coming from. I don't tend to ask questions in this manor, however it would be good to know why the method I am using isn't good and what improvements could be made. I'm not too sure hoe else to word it :/

Comment: The problem isn't *how* you're asking, it's *what* you're asking.  You don't have a specific problem, you have a regular expression that you'd like to "improve" - which is a highly subjective term.  Even if you defined a metric by which you could measure such improvement, there are too many ways to improve any particular metric, often involving tradeoffs in varying other metrics.  If you have a specific issue with the regular expression (If it's not matching correctly, or not replacing correctly), then we can help you, and whoever solves the problem can get credit. Otherwise, you're hamstrung.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - Thanks for explaining. I might try asking at codereview.stackexchange as it might be more appropriate to ask there

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/ helpful for learning regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

First, there are some problems with your second pattern.  It is not case insensitive (whereas the first pattern is) so it won't catch things like 'WWW'.  Maybe that's desirable, maybe not.  But it's also global, and is not anchored to the beginning of the URL.  So it will replace www anywhere in the URL.  Changing it to something like `/href=\'www/` and then changing the replace string to `href='http://www` should solve these problems.

Secondly, in a case like this, using 2 regular expressions may not be bad.  You can fold it into one regex if you want, but that doesn't mean it is any more efficient for the computer or the poor human who happens to be reading it.

All that said, one way to accomplish this with a single regular expression, is to do something like:

```
s = message.replace(/\[url=(?:http:\/\/)?([^\]]+)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href='http://$1'>$2</a>")
```

This may accomplish what you want.  It does not key off of "www", though, it simply prepends "http://" to any URL that does not already begin with that string.  It also doesn't support https, as you mentioned, but I'm not sure how you will support that anyway.  If all you are given is a URL with no protocol, how do you determine whether or not to make it https?

Comment: Thank you for the information and regex. It's exactly what I required :)

Comment: To support pass through HTTPS, you could use `\[url=(?:http(s?):\/\/)?([^\]]+)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/url\]/gi` and replace with `"<a href='http$1://$2'>$3</a>"`.  Then, at least, all HTTPS links would stay HTTPS, and all HTTP links would be HTTP.  Unspecified links would do what a browser would do, and assume HTTP.

Comment: Nice addition with the `http(s?):` pattern.